# How to wait for a spawned thread to finish in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety

I want to use threads to do some blocking work. What should I do to:

- Spawn a thread safely
- Do useful work
- Wait until the thread finishes
- Continue with the function

Here is my code:

```
import threading

def my_thread(self):
    # Wait for the server to respond..


def main():
    a = threading.thread(target=my_thread)
    a.start()
    # Do other stuff here
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`Thread.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join). Few lines from docs.

> Wait until the thread terminates. This blocks the calling thread until the thread whose join() method is called terminates – either normally or through an unhandled exception – or until the optional timeout occurs.

For your example it will be like.

```
def main():
    a = threading.thread(target = my_thread)
    a.start()
    a.join()
```